# how to get the result of matrices

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-decomposition, matrix-rank

Find a 2 × 2 matrix that rotates a plane by +45° (+45° means 45° counterclockwise).

Comment: [Relevant wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_a_2_by_2_matrix)

Comment: Write $X$ in coordinates and work out the algebra?  Expect multiple answers.

Comment: Also, I guess the determinant of $X$ has to be $\pm 2$.

Comment: You have changed your question completely. Why? You shold ask a new question.

Comment: This is irrelevant since the question has been totally changed!

Comment: *Chamaleon questions* are not welcome here. If you need to ask different questions, just ask separate questions. This applies also in the case a crucial typo makes a question completely different from the one is meant to be asked.

Comment: This is lame because (a) some people already spent time working on it and (b) it was a good question.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: it is easy to find a square root of a diagonal matrix, $D$, with nonnegative entries $d_i$ on the diagonal: it is simply another diagonal matrix, $D^{1/2}$, where each entry is $\pm \sqrt{d_i}$.

A similar trick works to find $X$ so $X^2=A$ when $A$ is diagonalizable. If $A=PDP^{-1}$, then $X=PD^{1/2}P^{-1}$ is a solution.

In your case, your matrix $A$ is diagonalizable.